# Making sure my custom Gradle configuration get its required dependencies

Tags: gradle

I have set up an integration test task in **gradle** as follows:

```
sourceSets {

    main {
        output.resourcesDir = output.classesDir
    }

    integrationTest {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/it/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/it/resources', 'src/main/resources']
        compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.testRuntime
        runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath
    }
}

   task integrationTest(type: Test) {
        description "Run the integration tests."
        testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
        classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
        reports.html.destination = file("$reports.html.destination/integration")
        reports.junitXml.destination = file("$reports.junitXml.destination/integration")
    }
```

But when I try to view the dependencies for these configurations (i.e. `integrationTestCompile` and `integrationTestRuntime`) they appear to be empty:

```
./gradlew bignibou-server:dependencies

integrationTest
No dependencies

integrationTestCompile - Compile classpath for source set 'integration test'.
No dependencies

integrationTestRuntime - Runtime classpath for source set 'integration test'.
No dependencies
```

I am not sure how to specify my **integrationTest** dependencies..

This does not work:

```
// Testing
testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
testCompile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:${springSecurityVersion}")
testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-core:${mockitoVersion}")
testCompile("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:${hamcrestVersion}")
testCompile("org.easytesting:fest-assert:${festVersion}")
testCompile("com.h2database:h2:${h2Version}")
testCompile("org.subethamail:subethasmtp:${wiserVersion}")
```

Otherwise the dependencies would appear above.

Can anyone please help?